# Adding a new record by using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am creating a test project in order to learn using `asp.net 5` and the `mvc 6` framework.

I have decided to create a simple webpage that each menu item comes from the database. To do so I have created a model like such

```
namespace TestTemplate.Models
{
    public class SideMenuItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Level { get; set; }

        public string Label { get; set; }

        public string Link { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Inside my Models folder I also have a file named `TestContext.cs'

```
namespace TestTemplate.Models
{
    public class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<SideMenuItem> SideMenuItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

That is my `EntityFramework DbContext` class.

When trying to create a new `SideMenu` item by using a simple view with a form to adding all the needed data, then using my angular factory that looks like this

```
return $resource('/api/sidemenu/:id');
```

I get the error:

```
An exception of type 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

-->System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'SideMenuItem'.
```

This error occurs on `SideMenuController.cs` where I define my API at the part where I am trying to Post the new item:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]SideMenuItem sideMenuItem)
{
    if (sideMenuItem.Id == 0)
    {
        _dbContext.SideMenuItems.Add(sideMenuItem);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();                        // ERROR HERE.
        return new ObjectResult(sideMenuItem);
    }
    else
    {
        var original = _dbContext.SideMenuItems.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == sideMenuItem.Id);
        original.Level = sideMenuItem.Level;
        original.Label = sideMenuItem.Label;
        original.Link = sideMenuItem.Link;
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return new ObjectResult(original);
    }
}
```

I also should mention that before running the app i used

```
>dnx ef migration add initial
>dnx ef database update
```

I believe it has to do with me not creating my database correctly. Since I am not seeing any folder on my project that had anything to do with databases or migrations.

Why is it complaining that `SideMenuItem` is invalid, and how can I fix the issue?

Comment: What's the inner exception?

Comment: Should be the part after `--->` if I am not mistaken. All other output does not seem very useful.

Comment: Check your database, does it contain a SideMenuItem table? Is the name exactly like that? (i.e. no "s" at the end)

Comment: Showing the inner exception might be really useful

Comment: Are you not missing a constructor in your context class. public TestContenxt() : base("TestContext") { }

Comment: If you check this [link] (http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: @CosmosBanda the link seems like a great starting point, Im thinking of starting my current test project from the start after following that tutorial.

Comment: I can also suggest to check out lynda.com mvc5 essential training. Great videos

Comment: Thanks, will do. My main reason for confusion is that this is an extremely new framework and some of the information out there is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to create my database again, I noticed that I had a typo on my migration command, hence the database was not created.

The command should have been `dnx ef migrations ...` with an s.

A good starting point with all the commands can be found [here](http://www.bricelam.net/2014/09/14/migrations-on-k.html).